# Benefit to use syntax code "persisted"

Tags: sql-server

I still don't understand about "persisted" when I have read about it.

What is the benefit to use SQL code "persisted" in a specific table in sql server.

What value do I get when I use sql code "persisted"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persisted is an option that can be specified when a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) is defined in a table. A computed column is a column in a table that is defined by a T-SQL expression to calculate its value. Such expression can contain references to other columns and / or utilize system or user defined scalar functions. Or more simply from the docs:

> A computed column is a virtual column that isn't physically stored in the table, **unless the column is marked PERSISTED**. A computed column expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs.

Without using the `PERSISTED` keyword, the expression is calculated every time that column is referenced and read from. This might be beneficial when the use cases for the table are more write-heavy than read-heavy.

Using the `PERSISTED` keyword causes the expression be calculated at the time the table is written to, and saved to disk (persisted) as if it were a regular column. This means all subsequent references that read from the computed column won't need to calculate the expression, because its results are already saved on disk. This is usually more beneficial when the table's use cases are more read-heavy than write-heavy.

This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991958/5059085) provides a little more details on the differences of when using the `PERSISTED` keyword or not:

> The computed value is **persisted** into the table, as if it were a normal column value.
>
> If you don't have `PERSISTED`, then the value is computed **every time** the column is accessed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991776/what-does-persisted-mean-in-sql-server-2012/28991958#28991958

Answer (score 3):

> What value do I get when I use sql code `persisted`?

`PERSISTED` defines whether or not the pre-calculated column value is stored in the data pages.

If you index the computed column then the computed column value will always be stored pre-calculated in those irrespective of whether or not you define it as "persisted"

There are some cases where the system forces you to do this

- computed columns used as partitioning columns of a partitioned table must be explicitly marked `PERSISTED` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#persisted))
- Or if wanting to index a computed column that is deterministic but not precise (e.g. a result of a floating point calculation) or the result of a CLR expression ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver16#determinism-requirements))
- Or if wanting to reference it in a Check constraint, Foreign key or `Not NULL` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#check))

Outside of such cases it is up to you to decide if you consider the additional cost of wider rows from having to store this information in the data pages would out weigh the *potential* * benefit of having the value pre-calculated so it need not be re-calculated at `SELECT` time.

---

<sup>*</sup> Even if marked as `PERSISTED` there is no guarantee that the expression will not be re-evaluated at runtime anyway. [This is something that trace flag 176 can help with if you encounter this.](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns)